# SQL Query with accents from Foreign Languages

Tags: sql-server-2005, internationalization, diacritics

I have a simple column filled with words, many from foreign languages,

I need to query based on the "English" letters,

ie E, e, é, è, etc should be returned for query of "E"

so école should be returned as a result which exists in the database when I query for "E"

I can't really find a way to Google this, so help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using MSSQL 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Change your collation to be [accent-insensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143515(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

choose a collation which is insensitive to accented characters

example

```
create table bla(Col nvarchar(30))

insert bla values (N'E')
insert bla values (N'e')
insert bla values (N'é')
insert bla values (N'è')
insert bla values (N'f')
insert bla values (N'k')


select * from bla where Col = 'e'  --won't work

select * from bla where Col = 'e' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI_WS
```